# How to add elements to list dynamicly with for loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have these foods: *meat*, *cheese*, *apple*
I've declared lists for them:

```
List<String> foods = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<>();
```

In `foods` I store their name and in the `quantity` their quantity. The maximum amount of one food is 7. For example, if we want to add 10 meat it must be stored like this:

| Lists | index 0 | index 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Foods | meat | meat |
| Quantity | 7 | 3 |

**Is there any way to do this or there is another (or simpler) technique for this?**

Comment: I would suggest that you come up with a better abstraction than Lists.  "objects" is too generic a name.  I would encapsulate quantity into the abstraction along with the collection.  Hide the messy details - that's what object-oriented programming is about.  What is the common abstraction here for "meal", "cheese", and "apple"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I agree 100% with duffymo.  But the answer to you question is that you add elements to a `List` using one of the `add` methods; see the javadocs for details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object to store item (meal/apple/cheese) and quantity, use while loop to iterate through quantity, and set Item object.

```
private static final int MAX_ALLOWED_QUANTITY = 7;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
    placeOrder(orderList, "meal", 10);
    
    for (Order orderObj : orderList)
        System.out.println("Item - "+orderObj.getItem()+", Quantity - "+orderObj.getQuantity());
}

private static void placeOrder(List<Order> orderList, String item, int quantity)
{
    while (quantity > 0)
    {
        Order orderObj = new Order();
        orderObj.setItem(item);

        if (quantity >= MAX_ALLOWED_QUANTITY)
            orderObj.setQuantity(MAX_ALLOWED_QUANTITY);
        else
            orderObj.setQuantity(quantity);

        orderList.add(orderObj);
        quantity = quantity - MAX_ALLOWED_QUANTITY;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Item - meal, Quantity - 7
Item - meal, Quantity - 3
```